# Mysql LIKE Clause and accents

Tags: mysql, utf-8, special-characters, sql-like

I'm creating a search engine with php and mysql.

It works but if I search for instance the word "publié", it will not find anything but if I search the word "Publie", it will show results embedding the term "publie" AND "publié".

How can I make the search accent-sensitive to get only the results matching exactly what I asked for, with or without accents?

Here is a typical request I use:

```
$requete4  = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        title,
        description, 
        CONCAT(
            IF (title LIKE '%".search_word."%', '1', '0'),
            IF (description LIKE '%".$search_word."%', '1', '0-')
        ) AS match_bitmask
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE 
    (
        title LIKE '%".$search_word."%' OR 
        description LIKE '%".$search_word."%'
    )
    ORDER BY id DESC 
");
```

Note1: all my tables, varchars and text fields in Mysql are utf8_general_ci.

Note 2: I tried to add "COLLATE utf8_general_ci" at the end of my request but I get an error message.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: «I get an error message» — Did you read it?

Comment: "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL". But, unless I use the Collate clause, my requests are perfectly valid and don't generate any exception.

Comment: That's a **PHP** error message that complaints you're trying to fetch rows from a query that failed. You need to fetch the **MySQL** error as well. Go to [`mysql_error()` manual page](http://php.net/mysql_error), scroll past the *do not use this extension* red notice and see the examples.

Comment: Ok, I did this and found the error but not the solution. Can you look at the comment I made to eggyal?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make the search accent-sensitive to get only the results matching exactly what I asked for, with or without accents?

Use the `utf8_bin` collation.  Either—

- change the collation of the columns:

  ```
  ALTER mytable
    MODIFY title       <datatype> COLLATE utf8_bin,
    MOFIFY description <datatype> COLLATE utf8_bin;
  ```
- explicitly specify the collation to be used in each `LIKE` expression:

  ```
  SELECT 
          title,
          description, 
          CONCAT(
              IF (title LIKE '%".$search_word."%' COLLATE utf8_bin, '1', '0'),
              IF (description LIKE '%".$search_word."%' COLLATE utf8_bin, '1', '0-')
          ) AS match_bitmask
      FROM mytable 
      WHERE 
      (
          title LIKE '%".$search_word."%' COLLATE utf8_bin OR 
          description LIKE '%".$search_word."%' COLLATE utf8_bin
      )
      ORDER BY id DESC
  ```

Comment: Well, I don't know why, the "Collate" clause always brings me an error message. I just put it exactly as you suggest it, just after the "like" clause and I get an "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL" for each line I added the "Collate" on. The message is not related to the Collate per se but it seems that it breaks something. Keep in mind that I don't have to alter the table as all the DB, tables and fields are in UTF8 already. I just checked. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Baylock: Just because the columns are *encoded* in UTF-8 does **not** mean that they will by default be using the `utf8_bin` *collation*, which is what the above `ALTER TABLE` command is designed to change.  There is, however, nothing wrong with the above `SELECT` statement (see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/070f0f/2)) - so your query must be failing due to some other problem: suggest that you output the result of `mysql_error()` to see what.

Comment: Ok, you were right, the error is this one: "COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'". I have hundreds of table rows, I just can't run your script against all of them, one by one. So I found this:" https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/How+to+Change+All+Columns'+Collation+to+utf8_bin+in+MySQL " I did it all and afterwards, everything is utf8_bin but then, I run against the same exact issues than before and the same error message if I use Collate.

Comment: I didi this but it didn't help neither: "SET NAMES utf8"